# How to add this webpack config to craco?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-scripts, craco

I'm trying to append the `react-scripts` webpack config with [craco](https://craco.js.org/) but I'm a little unsure as I've never used it before.

I am wanting to add this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922329/babel-cant-resolve-imports-in-it-its-own-source-code)):

```
const webpack5esmInteropRule = {
  test: /\.m?js/,
  resolve: {
    fullySpecified: false
  }
};

config.module.rules = [ webpack5esmInteropRule, ...otherRules ]
```

I have installed craco as a dependency and have created the `craco.config.js` but it is currently empty...

Comment: were you able to figure this out? how did you do it?

Comment: @Ram I don't believe so